# Update from play store / app store will cause my Flutter app to be restarted?

Tags: flutter

I'm setting up package store_redirect to have a screen that informs the user an update of the app is needed, with a button "update". The button will send the user to app store / play store where he will be able to update the app.

When app will be updated, if the user push back button, then a new and updated istance of my app will be executed by operating system?
Or I have to handle the possibility my old app version is still working in memory?

Answer (score 1):

When the user presses the update button in the play store he/she can still go back to the app till the play store finishes downloading the new app. When the play store starts installing the update the app will automatically close even if you are currently using the app. Then user will be able to use new app.

Answer (score 0):

When the user will click update button the OS will  **close** the current instance of your app and only after will install the new version

Comment: What do you mean with "will close"? When the button is pressed, the app is placed in background, still working, and it will be open the store. Indeed if I tap back button, I come back to my working app, in the same screen asking for update.
But, if I update, I suppose my app will be killed to allow updating operations. And, again, I suppose, the O.S. wil take care to re-execute my updated app when I will come back to it with back button.